# Skewed gaussian distribution within an ellipse with python

Tags: python, distribution, gaussian

Okay, so I've been pulling some hairs out over this for the last couple of days and haven't made much progress.
I want to generate a 2-D array (grid) of gaussian-*like* distribution on an elliptical domain. Why do I say gaussian-like?, well I want an asymmetric gaussian, aka skewed gaussian where the peak of the gaussian-like surface is at some point x0,y0 within the ellipse and the values on the perimeter of the ellipse are zero (or approaching zero...).
The attached picture might describe what I mean a little better.

[image: Skewed gaussian surface on an elliptical domain:]

Comment: and your problem is that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was able do figure out how to define a skewed gaussian in 1-D using the following:
`def skew(x,e,w,a):
  t = (x-e) / w
  return 2 * norm.pdf(t) * norm.cdf(a*t)`
but how do I define it over an elliptical domain and force it to decay to zero on the perimeter.