# How to draw such a picture with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster, shapefile, rasterio

Spatial changes in the average center and error ellipse of PM2.5 concentrations in China

[image]

Comment: I would suggest getting the data used, processing it, then using something like [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) to plot the data.

Comment: https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/

Comment: https://www.xarg.org/2018/04/how-to-plot-a-covariance-error-ellipse/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233301/skewed-gaussian-distribution-within-an-ellipse-with-python

Comment: Thank you for your information. I found the answer in the Directional Distribution of ArcGIS